# Mysql query to select rows and alternatively matching rows on other table

Tags: mysql, matching

I've got two tables:

`user`
ID --- Name

`posts`
ID --- UserID --- Text --- Postdate

Now I want to select all users and every post they've made in the past 15 minutes. I also want to display every user that didn't didn't even make a post with the matching conditions at all.

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
$user_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
while ($a = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_q))
{
     $post_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Userid=".$a['ID']." AND Postdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)");
     //Do anything with this information
}
```

Do you have any ideas how I can put all this information in just one query? Doing so many queries makes the server running very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a left outer join:

```
select u.*, p.*
from users u left outer join
     posts p
     on u.id = p.userid and
        p.Postdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

The `left outer join` keeps all the rows in the first table.  If nothing matches in the second table, using the condition, then the values are `NULL` for those fields.

EDIT:

If you want to limit this to 50 random users, you can do this at the `users` level:

```
select u.*, p.*
from (select u.*
      from users u
      order by rand()
      limit 50
     ) u left outer join
     posts p
     on u.id = p.userid and
        p.Postdate >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE);
```

The `order by rand()` makes them random.  You could order by anything -- name, date created, whatever.  You can even leave the `order by` out and just take 50 arbitrary rows returned by the database.

Comment: that's interesting, thank you! And how do I output this? would it be packed in one bundle for every user or would there be an extra row for every post - regardless on the user.

Comment: @TobiasBaumeister . . . As written, there would be one row for every  for every post that matches, with both the user and post information.  If there is no post, there would still be a row output.  That row would have the user data and `NULL`s for the post columns

Comment: I see, thank you. And what do I have to do if I want to LIMIT this query to 50 users? If I just put this at the end of my query, then is returns 50 rows, but less users, since many users made more than one post.